# Multiple conditions using for loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'm beginning programming with codecademy and I tried to write a "search for word" program, but I don't know how to write a condition in `if` using a `for` loop to check all the letters in a search word, no matter the length.

I know the for loop gives me `true` or `false`, but I would like it to generate as many `text[j] === myWord[j-i]` conditions to my code as there are letters.

Is there something wrong with my syntax or should I use other command that I don't know of?

```js
var text = "Within the field of literary criticism, text also refers to the original information content of a particular piece of writing; that is, the text of a work is that primal symbolic arrangement of letters as originally composed, apart from later alterations, deterioration, commentary, translations, paratext, etc. Therefore, when literary criticism is concerned with the determination of a text, it is concerned with the distinguishing of the original information content from whatever has been added to or subtracted from that content as it appears in a given textual document (that is, a physical representation of text).";

var myWord = "literary";
var hits = [];

for (var i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (for (var j=i; j<(i + myWord.length); j++){
            text[j]===myWord[j-i]
        })
        hits.push(text[i])
    }
}

if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `if` condition inside the inner loop like below

```
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < (i + myWord.length); j++){
            if(text[j]===myWord[j-i])
                hits.push(text[i]);
        }       
    }
}
```